# Does cloud run support htaccess file?

Tags: angular, .htaccess, google-cloud-run

I have an angular application with SSR mode deployed on google Cloud Run.

To enhance SEO, I need to apply some redirection rules like Removing trailing slash from non-file path URLs and forcing HTTPS and WWW.

So, I have created the file on the root directory and added it to the build folder by adding the file on angular.json

This is my .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
AllowOverride All
#### Force HTTPS://WWW and remove trailing / from files ####
## Turn on rewrite engine
RewriteEngine on

# Remove trailing slash from non-filepath urls
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(.+)/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ https://example.com/%1 [R=301,L]

# Include trailing slash on directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.+)/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ https://example.com/$1/ [R=301,L]

# Force HTTPS and WWW
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.(.*)$ [OR,NC]
RewriteCond %{https} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

When I call https://example.com/link1/ it should redirect to https://example.com/link1 but it is not the case.

I think cloud run is not using my htaccess file, any help?

Comment: `AllowOverride All` - This directive is what enables `.htaccess` files on _Apache_ (specifically, it allows `.htaccess` overrides) - it cannot go in the `.htaccess` file itself and must go in the server config. Attempting to use this directive in `.htaccess` would result in an error (so, yes, it would seem the `.htaccess` file is not currently being processed, or mod_rewrite is not enabled.) (Although I'm not sure how this relates to google-cloud-run.)

Comment: This is a webserver configuration issue and is not a Cloud Run issue. Edit your question with the webserver configuration files.

Comment: @MrWhite I am not sure too, but for sure the file is not being processed,

Comment: @JohnHanley   the app is deployed on cloud run with a docker image, I don't have a web server like in normal situation, using cloud run allow me to deploy quickly and avoid  all infrastructure management

Comment: .htaccess is an Apache configuration file. If you want to use Apache features, then configure Apache in your container.